# Custom binning in sklearn.preprocessing?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a list of continuous variables called size_array. I've been scaling them from `[0, 1]` like this:

```
max_abs_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaled = max_abs_scaler.fit_transform(size_array)
```

Is there a way to scale them on the range of `[-1, 1]` where the median (or a percentile) is 0? My data is right skewed, so the values above the median are spread out a lot and the values to the left of the median are not spread out. I tried to scaling them with this method:

```
def using_median():
    if x >= median:
        return (x - median)/(max - median)
    else:
        return (median - x)/(median - min)
```

But that didn't work. Is there any other way to do this with `sklearn.preprocessing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [PowerTransformer()](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/preprocessing.html#mapping-to-a-gaussian-distribution). It can work very well for skewed distributions.

check out this example:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pt = preprocessing.PowerTransformer()
X_lognormal = np.random.RandomState(616)\
    .lognormal(size=(300, 2))

_,ax = plt.subplots(1,2,sharey=True)
ax[0].hist(X_lognormal)

ax[1].hist(pt.fit_transform(X_lognormal))
```

[image]

Comment: That looks like it could work well! Do you know of any transformations that use 0 for the median instead of the mean like this one does? I'd like to be able to change what percentile of the data that 0 lies on if possible, like the 75th percentile for example.

Comment: I don't think any transformation exists for getting median to be 0 or any nth percentile to be 0.

Comment: I made a custom algorithm to transform it. Thanks!